# How to add a list of str + int using list comprehension?

Tags: python

Ok, first of all, I'm a total newb in python.
So, what I'm trying to achieve is creating a list of lists, in which first element is a string and second is an integer.
First, I enter a number of sets and then every set on a new line, so it looks like this:

```
3
Alex 40
Boris 30
Claire 50
```

This seems to be working

```
n = int(input())
nums = []
for i in range(n):
    num = input().split()
    num[1] = int(num[1])
    nums.append(num)
```

But I've been trying to improve this method:

```
n = int(input())
nums = []
for i in range(n):
    nums.append([[x, int(y)] for x, y in input().split()])
```

Which in return gives me "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's what `input().split()` is doing under-the-hood:

```
input().split()
"Boris 30".split()
["Boris", "30"]
```

Every time you iterate over `["Boris", "30"]`, it'll yield first `"Boris"` and then `"30"`. So when you do

```
[... for x, y in input().split()]
```

What you're actually doing is:

```
[... for x, y in ["Boris", "30"]]
```

At first it may look it's doing the right thing, but it's trying to unpack the string `"Boris"` into `x` and `y` (thus the "too many values to unpack" error: it expected only 2 values, but it received 5). Note that if `"Boris"` was replaced with `"Bo"`, the code would not raise this specific error (but it still wouldn't do what you're expecting).

You can fix this by unpacking the `input().split()` itself:

```py
n = int(input())
nums = []
for i in range(n):
    x, y = input().split()
    nums.append([x, int(y)])
```

Answer (score 2):

Split the user input into a list, and remove the unnecessary list comprehension. Also, provide meaningful messages to the user:

```
n = int(input('enter the number of lines: '))
nums = []
for i in range(n):
    lst = input('enter name and age: ').split()
    nums.append([lst[0], int(lst[1])])
print(nums)
```